# How to set closure on navigation bar when isHidden property change?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I use `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` for hide navigation bar. And I need to observe isHidden property for some action when it triggered.

Comment: Subclass `UINavigationController`, implement `didSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use KVO, rx.observe in RXSwift library, and observe the value of isNavigationBarHidden property .

please check the link.
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#rxobserveweakly

or using FLAG to make it true or false on hide and show the navigation bar or any event related to that, and make that variable observable with RXSwift.